# Using python and Azure Topics, is it possible to use long polling

Tags: python, azure, amqp, azureservicebus

I am trying to access Azure ServiceBus Topics using python.  From what I've been reading, I can access this using AMQP and proton-python.

In the .net world, there is the concept of long-polling, where you wait for a message to arrive.

Is such a concept available using AMQP and python?

Comment: AMQP doesn't long-poll. It uses a single persistent connection. If you can use it, it will be more efficient. (Beware of partitioning!)

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed. I've been asking the same question via Javascript and Node.js. It is possible but the load balancer on the Azure side kicks idle connections after 230 seconds. I'm told this time varies but in my own experimentation it has been consistent so far. This is because it uses a REST connection. You can however implement it with Proton-Python as you have suggested. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj841070.aspx) for more information. I'm working on doing just that at the minute.